# Update xml elemnt inside function. How to pass elemnt inside function

Tags: php, xml

```
showOrUpdate($day->Date, $_POST['Date'])
```

and function:

```
function showOrUpdate($element, $value)
{
    if (isset($value) && !empty($value))
    {   
        $element = $value;
    } 

    return $element;
}
```

but problem is that `$element` is not passed as element but is passed as readable value and is then for example 2013-08-22 and not `$day->Date`.

but I want to pass it in function and inside function update value and later save it.

like:

```
$day->Date =  $value;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is commonly know as pass by reference. When defining a function use the '&' sign for variables that you want to pass by reference.

```
function showOrUpdate(&$element, $value) {
  if (isset($value) && !empty($value))   
    $element = $value; 
}
```

This would update the original value of $element. Also, in this situation you don't need to use a return statement as the variable has already been modified within the function itself.